# Editar Latex no Vim e Aspell - Acentos

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, acentuação, latex

Olá, estou tentando usar o VIM para editar um arquivo em Latex. 
Ao escrever o texto em Latex no mesmo consigo acentuar normalmente, tendo dificuldade para corrigir o mesmo no Aspell ou no Texmaker:

Escrevo no VIM: `*estratégicas*`

Aparece no Aspell: `*Estrat\égicas*`

Desta forma não consigo corrigir a ortografia do meu texto.

Eu já inclui no preambulo do meu arquivo `.tex`:

```
\usepackage[portugues]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{aeguill}
```

Tem alguma forma de salvar o aquivo `.tex` na forma em que eu consiga usar o Aspell ou Texmaker?

Comment: Tenta usar a acentuação no formato : `Estrat\'egicas`, tive um problema parecido

Comment: Obrigado @Tuxpilgrim, mas tentei usar tal forma de formato de acentuação, mas o Aspell continua reconhecendo a palavra como se fosse duas (ele divide `*Estrat\'egicas*` em `*Estrat*` e `*egicas*`.